# Populating form data from jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, populate

Wondering if someone could take a look at my code and point me in the right direction. 
When you type a name, it should autocomplete and auto-populate the dept and phone fields.
If I remove $getName = $_REQUEST['term'] and replace it with $getName = "John Doe", it works, but loses dynamicity.

Jquery

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#name').autocomplete({
                source:'pop.php', 
                minLength:2,
                select:function(evt, ui)
                {
                    $(this).focusout(function(e) {
                        this.form.dept.value = ui.item.dept;
                        this.form.phone.value = ui.item.phone; 
                        this.form.ext.value = ui.item.ext; 
                    });

                }
            });
        });
```

HTML form

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name"/>
    <input id="dept" type="text" name="dept"/>
    <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone"/>
    <input id="ext" type"text" size="4" name ="ext" maxlength="4" />     
</form>
```

PHP:

```
//Get request variable
$getName = $_REQUEST['term'];

//Explode text field into into variables
list($fname,$lname) = explode(' ', $getName, 2);


$data = array();

//Build query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE fname LIKE '$fname%' AND lname LIKE '$lname%' LIMIT 10";

//Execute Query
$resultSet = $mysqli->query($sql);

//Loop through the query
while($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{

    $data[] = array(
        'value' =>$row['fname'] .' '. $lname['lname'],
        'dept'  =>$row['dept'],
        'phone' =>$row['phone'],
        'ext'   =>$row['ext']
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```